# Getting error - Can't set 'headers' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am stuck with this error - `Can't set Headers of Undefined`.

Code Reference

---

Defined Headers seperately:

```
var headers = function (req,res,next){
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "[*]");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS");

    console.log("Inside headers")
}
```

Defined the first function I wish to run:

```
var middleware1 = function (req, res, next) {
    headers();

    console.log("Before Get method middleware")
    console.log("middleware1");

    collection.find({}, {
        name: 'Task 1'
    }).toArray((error, result) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log("It is the find -> /tasks method error");

            return res.status(500).send(error);
        }

        next();
    })
}
```

Defined the second function:

```
var middleware2 = function (req, res, next) {
    headers();
    console.log("middleware2");
    
    collection.find({}, {name: 'Task 4'}).toArray((error, result) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log("It is the find -> /tasks method error");

            return res.status(500).send(error);
        }
    })
    next();
}
```

Defined the validateParams:

```
Defined the Final value to be run:
```

```
const fn1 = (req, res, next) => {
middleware1();

console.log("1");
next();
};

 const fn2 = (req, res, next) =>{
middleware2();

console.log("2");
next();
};

 const fn3 = (req, res, result) => {
 collection.find({}).toArray((error, result) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log("It is the find -> /tasks method error");
        return res.status(500).send(error);
    }

    res.send(result);
    console.log("result");
  });
  };
```

```
**Final Call**
```

````
  app.get("/2498", function fn1(req, res, next) {  
  headers(req, res, next);

    

        //In Going the right way --> Task 1 to Task 4     

              middleware1(req, res, next);

              console.log("1");
              // next();
              },
              function fn2 (req,res,next) {
              
                headers(req, res, next);

                middleware2(req, res, next);

                console.log("2");
                // next();
              } ,function fn3  (req,res,next) {

              headers(req, res, next);

              collection.update(
                
                  { 'taskId': 1,   'parent': 'yes!' ,  'projectId' : 1,   
   'content': { 'name': 'Task 1', 'predecessors':[], 'successor': [2] } },
                  { 'taskId': 4,   'parent': 'na' ,    'projectId' : 2, 
  'content': { 'name': 'Task 6' , 'predecessors':[], 'successor': [3] } }
                  ).toArray((error, result) => {

                if(error) {
                    console.log("It is the find -> /tasks method error");
            
                    return res.status(500).send(error);   
                }
                console.log("Inside getToBeAssumed  --> Task 4  
           .....validateParams.....");
            
               console.log("The end = ", result);

                             
              })
              })
              ```
````

---

Error in Detail:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'setHeader' of undefined
> at headers (D:\mongodb_test_app\app-module-1.js:231:7)
> at fn1 (D:\mongodb_test_app\app-module-1.js:303:7)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\mongodb_test_app\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at next (D:\mongodb_test_app\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
> at Route.dispatch (D:\mongodb_test_app\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\mongodb_test_app\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at D:\mongodb_test_app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
> at Function.process_params (D:\mongodb_test_app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
> at next (D:\mongodb_test_app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
> at SendStream.error (D:\mongodb_test_app\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:121:7)
> at SendStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at SendStream.error (D:\mongodb_test_app\node_modules\send\index.js:270:17)
> at SendStream.onStatError (D:\mongodb_test_app\node_modules\send\index.js:421:12)
> at next (D:\mongodb_test_app\node_modules\send\index.js:735:16)
> at onstat (D:\mongodb_test_app\node_modules\send\index.js:724:14)
> at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:183:21)

Comment: When you call a function you actually need to pass arguments otherwise all the parameters will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling:

```
headers();
```

and

```
middleware1();
```

and

```
middleware2();
```

But, all those functions need several arguments.  You need to pass those arguments:

```
headers(req, res, next);
middleware1(req, res, next);
middleware2(req, res, next);
```

Technically, the only argument the `headers` function actually uses is `res` so you could change its definition to just have one argument `res` and pass just that one.

Comment: Hi @jfriend00  .... I did the following updation. but it did not work out either. Can you please suggest some other method ?

Comment: @SuchetaShrivastava - Well, you're also calling `middleware1();` and `middleware2()` so not passing the arguments to those either.  Seriously, you CAN'T use arguments if the caller isn't passing them - in all of your code.  We have pointed this out to you.  We shouldn't have to find all instances of that in your code - you should be able to do that yourself.  Also, it is BASIC debugging to examine what your arguments are with `console.log()` or in the debugger when you get errors like this.  You should be doing that yourself long before coming here.  This is basic debugging.

Comment: @SuchetaShrivastava - Note, you will create other problems when you fix this because you're trying to call `next()` more than once in both `middleware1` and in `fn1`.  Can't do that.  This code has lots of mistakes in it.  You are trying to treat asynchronous functions that indicate completion by calling `next()` like they are synchronous which will not work.

Comment: Hi @jfriend00 .... when I commented next() in --> app.get('/2498',....)  ----> I got this error -->TypeError: final argument to `executeLegacyOperation` must be a callback

Comment: Can you please help me out how to put a "The End" to all the errors in my code for its smooth functioning

Comment: @SuchetaShrivastava - I don't' know how to rewrite your code because some of it doesn't accomplish anything, so we don't know what the objective of this code is.  Doing database calls in some sort of middleware like `middleware1()` and `middleware2()` and then not doing anything with the database results is pointless.  For someone to help you rewrite all this, you would have to back up a couple steps and describe in words what you are trying to accomplish and it needs to be detailed and accurate enough that a contractor could implement it from the description of the objective.

Comment: Hi @jfriend00.... I am sorry,  there was a mistake in my code. I mentioned the correct code.